# how to add a browser list to cssnext

Tags: autoprefixer, postcss, cssnext

I am using [postcss-cssnext](https://github.com/MoOx/postcss-cssnext) and in my webpack.config I removed **autoprefixer**

```
postcss: [autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] }) ],
```

and included **cssnext**. I understand that cssnext already includes autoprefixer so we don't need both included. I am just wondering how I pass in the [browserslist](https://github.com/ai/browserslist) to cssnext? This is what I currently have:

```
postcss: [cssnext()],
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same question with gulp. Here is what I used.

```
postcss: [cssnext({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] })]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the options work the same for cssnext: [cssnext usage](http://cssnext.io/usage/)

*This is the exact same option that you might know from Autoprefixer. Since cssnext includes Autoprefixer, the option is propagated.*

Answer (score 0):

I am using Gulp.js and here is my code thar run everytime i use postcss-cssnext to auto put vendor prefixes in my CSS styles.

var plugins = [
   cssnext({browsers: ['last 2 versions']})];